# How to get Email Addresses of the invitees in Firebase?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get e-mail address of the people the user has invited from my app

This is my code:

```
private void onInviteClicked() {
    Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.invitation_message))
            .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_deep_link)))
            .setCustomImage(Uri.parse("http://jennstrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/bad-profile-pic-2.jpeg"))
            .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.invitation_cta)).setCallToActionText("email").build();

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
}

int REQUEST_INVITE = 10101;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: requestCode=" + requestCode + ", resultCode=" + resultCode);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_INVITE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the invitation IDs of all sent messages
            final String[] ids = AppInviteInvitation.getInvitationIds(resultCode, data);
            final List<String> members = new ArrayList();

            members.add(GoogleAuthHelper.getInstance().getUser().getProjectId());
            for (String id : ids) {
                members.add(id);
            }

            ApiClient.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addMembers(members, new OnPostListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                    Log.e("Server", "Members: " + error.getErrorCode());
                }
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String val) {
                    Log.d("Server", "Response from Member: " + val.toString());
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Sending failed or it was canceled, show failure message to
            // the user
            // ...
            Log.d("Server", "Invitation Failed code: " + resultCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Now how do I get the email addresses of the list of people the user has invited. `AppInviteInvitation.getInvitationIds()` are not the email ids. Someone help me out! Please!